# Create keystore file with one command

Tags: java, android, linux, command-line-interface, keystore

I have a script which creates and signs a keystore file for an android app.

It is working perfectly fine but i would rather have it run without human intervention

what i have to create the keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This then prompts me to enter the following values manually using the terminal: keystore password, full name , organisation unit, organisation name, city , state, county code,  key password.

what i have to sign the app:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

This then prompts me to enter passphrase for keystore.

Is there anyway i can pass these values in as parameters so the full script runs without anyother interaction needed?

PS: i'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks For your time :)

Comment: Bear in mind that if you enter passwords etc as parameters, they can be stored in your history/logs

Comment: @fractalwrench Thanks for bringing that to my attention, i'll need to find a work around for that.

Comment: Env vars are a classic workaround for avoiding using passwords as plain text arguments.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do something like this to generate the keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias replserver \
    -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks \
    -dname "CN=Mark Smith, OU=JavaSoft, O=Sun, L=Cupertino, S=California, C=US" \
    -storepass password -keypass password
```

Here is a good reference : https://pubs.vmware.com/continuent/tungsten-replicator-3.0/deployment-ssl-stores.html.  And for the jarsigner there is "storepass" parameter for the keystore password.  And if you put both in a script you should be good.

Comment: Add `-deststoretype pkcs12` to create the keystore in the now recommended industry standard `PKCS12` format. Another good option is `-keysize 4096`

Comment: Also put `-validity 365000` (100 years) if you plan on using the keystore for app publishing. Your certificate must not lose its validity or your users cannot update anymore. You cannot replace the keystore once your app is out in the wild.